# SQL Server CONTAINS (full-text search) returns incorrect values

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I see that the character `'№'` is ignored. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mytable 
WHERE contains(Field, '"Направление №8"')
```

returns:

```
 Направление №8
 Направление Москва-Минск
 Направление №10
 Направление N7
```

I need the character `'№'` to be used in the query.

How to resolve the problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: You should probably add the sql-server tag if it is your database management system, the solution is probably dependent on it and it will attract more potential answerers. In any case, add the relevant RDBMS tag.

Comment: Column data type and collation?

Comment: [varchar](max) NULL (Cyrillic_General_CI_AS)

Comment: any more ideas?